# Shell script with a for-loop

Tags: shell, for-loop, sh

how can we put a list in a for-loop in a shell script?
I mean imagine that we have 1000 strings : string1.yaml  ...  string1000.yaml  and we want to write a list
LL={string1.yaml  ...  string1000.yaml}
and say in the script:

```
for i in LL
do
...
done
```

specially it is a problem with the line breaking  if one writes them simply one after another

```
for i in  string1.yaml  ... string1000.yaml
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In POSIX shell, there's isn't really a good way. The naive approach:

```
LL="a b c d e"
for i in $LL; do
 ...
done
```

relies on the fact that no element in your list contains the delimiter (here, a space). If you know ahead of time what characters are *not* in your list, you can play with `IFS`. For instance, if you know that no item will contain a comma, you could use

```
LL="a,b c,d,e"   # Yes, the second item is "b c"
# This is not a perfect way to backup IFS; I'm ignoring the corner
# case of what happens if IFS is currently unset.
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
for i in $LL; do
   ...
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

If you are actually using `bash` or another more modern shell, you can use an array, which was specifically introduced for this kind of problem. An array is essentially a second level of quoting, so you don't need to provide an explicit delimiter yourself.

```
LL=(a "b c" d e)   # Four items, the second item contains a space
for i in "${LL[@}}"; do
  ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a massive amount of items you want to process, you probably want to put them in a **separate file** and read them like this:

```
$ cat strings.txt
string1.yaml
[...]
string1000.yaml
$ cat loop.sh
while IFS= read -r line
do
    [...] "$line"
done < strings.txt
```

This way you avoid cluttering code with data, and the is POSIX compliant without being overly complex.